# Git: Determine if all local commits exist in the upstream regardless of branch?

Tags: git

I want to check that all commits (that are on a branch or stash) exist in the remote repo.  I'm in the process of deleting old and unused repos from my computer, but before I delete it I want to ensure that I don't have any work in progress that I may forgot to push upstream.

For the current branch this is trivial, but I'm not sure the easiest way to check all branches?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "this is trivial" you mean that you have a method for a single branch:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads |
while read branch; do
    # see if $branch is safe, using your trivial method
    check_branch $branch
done
```